# How to check for an optional field in jq?

Tags: jq

I have this `jq` filter:

```
some_command | jq -r '.elements[] | select(.state=="LIVE" and .group == "some_text" and .someFlag == false) | .name'
```

`someFlag` is an optional field.  Hence, when it is absent, the expression doesn't show any result.  I want to check for:

- if someFlag is present, pass the check only if it has the `false` value
- if someFlag is not present, treat it as `false`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the alternative operator, `//`:

```
(.someFlag // false) == false)
```

So, if `.someFlag` isn't there, it is treated as false.

The whole expression is:

```
some_command | jq -r '.elements[] | select(.state=="LIVE" and .group == "some_text" and (.someFlag // false) == false)) | .name'
```

From `jq` documentation:

> **Alternative operator //**:
>
> A filter of the form `a // b` produces the same
>   results as `a`, if a produces results other than false and null.
>   Otherwise, `a // b` produces the same results as `b`.
>
> This is useful for providing defaults: `.foo // 1` will evaluate to 1 if
>   there’s no `.foo` element in the input. It’s similar to how or is
>   sometimes used in Python (jq’s or operator is reserved for strictly
>   Boolean operations).

Comment: This proposal does not accord with the stated requirements, as can be seen by considering what happens if "someFlag" is specified as `null`.

Answer (score 5):

In the given context, the direct translation of:

> - if someFlag is present, pass the check only if it has the false value
> - if someFlag is not present, treat it as false

to jq is:

```
if has("someflag") then .someflag == false else false end
```

### Adjusted filter

```
.elements[]
| select(.state == "LIVE"
         and .group == "some_text"
         and (if has("someFlag")
              then .someFlag == false 
              else false
              end))
| .name
```

---

<sub>[This response has been updated in accordance with the update to the Q.]</sub>